# Not able to convert to required Date format in Apache Ni-Fi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to convert the date **14-JUL-16 11.37.42.649000000 AM**
into **07/14/2016 11:37:42** fomat

My Ni-Fi command is

```
${LastContactTimestamp:toDate("dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS"):format("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")}
```

I am getting the error "Caused by: org.apache.nifi.attribute.expression.language.exception.**IllegalAttributeException**: Cannot parse attribute value as a date; date format: dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss.SSSXXX; attribute value: 14-JUL-16 11.37.42.649 AM"

tried to replace the Miliseconds but getting the same error

```
${LastContactTimestamp:replaceAll('(\.\d{3})\d*','$1'):toDate("dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss.SSSXXX"):format("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")}
```

how do I convert into proper date format in Apache-NiFi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to replace the colons in your first date format string with dots. 
Also your millisecond precision does not line up.
I guess the following should do the job:

```
dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS aa
```

So putting that together your expression will look something along the lines of:

```
${LastContactTimestamp:toDate("ddd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS aa"):format("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")}
```

The available format options and their mappings can be seen [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

---

Currently I'm unable to fact check this in my NiFi but will do so tomorrow evening.

Comment: i edited my mili seconds precision..still getting the error..what is "aa" btw  ?

Comment: @praveensangalad Did you also replace the colons between hours, minutes and milliseconds with dots? aa stands for AM / PM, see the added link for more information.

Comment: @praveensangalad Unlike in regular expression a dot inside a Java date format string matches an actual dot `.`, the same applies for the colon `:`. In your input string not colons but dots are used to separate the hour from the minutes. Thus using colons does not work.